# Is there a practical reason for why List<T>.IndexOf(T) does not return a nullable int?

Tags: c#, list, nullable

The method [`List<T>.IndexOf()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bd0tetb.aspx) returns [the zero-based index of the first occurrence of item within the entire List, if found; otherwise, –1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17.aspx).

I'm seeing a parallel between that, and something I just read in [Code Complete](http://www.cc2e.com/Default.aspx), which is telling me to "avoid variables with hidden meanings".

> For example: 
>   The value in the
>   variable pageCount might represent the number of pages printed, unless
>   it equals -1, in which case it indicates that an error has occurred.

Well, I don't know if the meaning is "hidden", because it's documented clearly enough, but **null** seems to convey better meaning to me than **-1**, and [.HasValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094.aspx) reads like a much better check than **> -1**.  As far as I can tell, List and nullable types were both introduced in C# 2.0, so I don't think the reason for retuning an `int` has to do with backwards compatibility. So, do you know if there was a reason, or if this was just something that someone forgot to implement, and we now have to live with that mistake forever?

Comment: In many situations, "magic values" can cause problems because one cannot guarantee that they won't occur.  For example, if one had a queue of `int`, and a `GetNextIfAny()` which would return the next enqueued integer, or -1 if there was none, it would be possible that a return value of -1 might mean there were no items, or it might mean that a -1 was placed in the queue.  Even if one doesn't expect any negative numbers to be in the queue, one should still allow for that possibility.  By contrast, there is no way an element can ever be found in location -1 of a `System.Array`.

Comment: The same goes for any other negative integer.

Comment: My point was that there is at least one value that `IndexOf` can return would could not represent a real index (-1).  There are other possible values it could return for other purposes, but since `IndexOf` only reports one type of 'not found' condition, a single magic value is sufficient.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

List was released with the 2.0 version of the run time as was nullable T.  But List implements [IList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.indexof.aspx) which existed with the 1.0 version of the runtime which not only didn't have nullable it didn't support generics.  To meet the contract of the IList interface an implementer must return -1 on indexof failure.  Code complete also maintains that you must meet the contracts you agree to and therefore List.Indexof must return -1.

---

Answer to Comment:

By the time the 2.0 runtime with generics there were already thousands of applications written against the non generic version.  That code would be allowed to function most effectively be migrated by supporting the generic interface as an extension of the non-generic interfaces.  Also, image having to classes with the same name and 90% same usage but in the case of a couple of methods totally different semantics.

Comment: Returning `-1` isn't really *failure*.  In case of failure, an exception would be thrown.

Comment: What was the point of implementing the three non-generic interfaces, then, along with their generic equivalents? (Not that IList<T>.IndexOf fixes the problem.)

Answer (score 6):

`System.Collections.Generic.List` may have been introduced in .NET 2.0, along with nullable, but the usage of -1 predates that considerably.  `ArrayList.IndexOf()`, `Array.IndexOf()`, `String.IndexOf()`, `SelectedIndex` of a listbox, etc.  So `List<T>` most likely did the same for consistency with the existing library.  (And in fact even classic VB has this meaning, so it even predates .NET 1.0)

As [@rerun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10864994/103167) points out, it isn't just stylistic consistency, it's actually part of the interface contract.  So +1 to him.

While `List<T>` didn't have to follow in the footsteps of `ArrayList` and didn't have to implement `IList`, doing so made it much more useful to programmers already familiar with those.

Comment: Furthermore, it's consistent with Java API which is probably a good idea given the relationship.

Comment: @Nadir: and Java used that for consistency with even earlier libraries

Comment: I don't think "useful" is the right word. As someone without a history of using the -1, it doesnt have the same connotation, and seems like a hack.

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess, but I would think it has to do with historical reasons and readability. Even though -1 is a "special value", it will never be returned in any other case. The rule you quoted in my opinion is primarily to keep you from returning values that could have more than one meaning. -1 is standard in c++ and similar languages, so it has become somewhat of an idiom across languages. Also, while hasvalue might be more readable, I think it would be best to have the same style consistently across the framework, which would require starting from the ground up. Finally, IMHO, in my limited experience, because nullable types have to be unboxed in order to use them elsewhere, they can be more trouble than they're worth, but that's just me.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's for backwards compatibility, as in framework 1.1 there wasn't nullables and the API was created back then.

Comment: `List<T>` certainly wasn't included in .Net 1.1.

Comment: What API?  Like I said, List couldn't have been in there at that point, because there were no generics.

Comment: But a- `List<T>` implements `IList` and b- the behavior was defined in framework 1, for `IList.IndexOf()`. Imagine the caos if `IList` returned `int` (and -1 for non-existing items) and `IList<T>` returned `int?`with a different behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The reason may be the simple fact that `Nullable<T>` (the actual type used when you write `T?`) involves unwanted complexity for something as simple as an index search. For `T? x` doing `x == null` is really only syntactic sugar for `x.HasValue` and when it turns out it's not `null` you'd still have to access the actual value through `x.Value`.

You don't really gain anything in comparison to just returning a negative value, which is not a valid index either. In fact, you make things just more complex.

Comment: +1 for the part about added complexity

Comment: I think the null-coalescing operator subverts the issue you're commenting on.

Comment: In which way? You'd still have to extract the value from the nullable result on wour own. `a ?? b` for nullables is the same as `a.HasValue ? a : b`, i.e. it doesn't extract the value for you.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but on the other side of the fence in VB, do default properties solve this problem?

Comment: @Wombo In this way: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx.  The operator can indeed extract the value for you, into a non-nullable int, so if you want to deal with a magic number, you could implement that yourself (int y = x ?? -1;).

Comment: Ah ok, but that's entirely besides the point. You wouldn't want to access an invalid index anyway, so the only time you actually need the value is when the index is valid - and at that point `??` would be the last thing you'd want to use.

Comment: It's not something I would want to use.  It sounds like something you would want to use, if you really think using .Value is more complex than dealing with -1.  If IndexOf() returned what I want it to, -1 lovers always could code exactly the same as did, except they could explicitly define the magic number, using the null-coalescing operator.

Answer (score 0):

This follows the same pattern as `String.IndexOf`, and many other implementations and variations of `IndexOf` methods, not only in the .NET libraries.

Using -1 as return value is a magic number, and those should normally be avoided. However, this pattern is well known, which is clearly an advantage when you implement a library method.

Comment: Still, newer APIs could use nullable. I can only think of WPFs ShowDialog() but there probably are more.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Yes, it could, but it would surprise a lot of people.